# How to install Android-studio? with ppa from official page

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, android

I tried to install Android studio but I think I got it: wrong `wget` link or something.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.5.1.0/android- studio-ide-141.2456560-linux.zip -p /opt/
apt-get install unzip
unzip android-studio-ide-141.2456560-linux.zip -d /opt
/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh -y
./studio.sh
```

Comment: What error messages do you see?

Comment: As the post currently stands, the URL has an erroneous spacing in it. Are you sure that's what you typed?

Comment: I have no idea what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in your terminal

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

After it's isntalled run it by typing `studio` in Dash (Search)